# A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint Error While Using SOAP 1.2 in WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, envelope

I am getting this error "A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint" when I sent a post request, but the matter is my Soap version is already 1.2 and all definitions are done in the wsdl file. Two sample request headers are below:

When the envelope in requests is soapenv:"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", it works perfectly and I can get a response from my application.

When the envelope in requests is xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" the error occures in the title of this question.

All messages I use must be with the seccond envelope. Whow can I make that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Review:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24965/faults.htm#WSADV633

replace all occurences:
xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"

for:
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"